# Flutter's applications default color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a `Welcome Screen` which has two `TextButtons` each wrapped in a `Container`.
one for Creating an account and another for logging in
(both of them have some shadow below them )
[image]

I managed to make both containers in flutter but I found out that the background color of the application is not pure white (#FFFFFF) which mean if I set the color of the login container to `Colors.white` it won't look like the background color of the app like above picture.

So I need a way to set the color of the login container to the same color as the application.
let's avoid hard coding I don't want to determine the background color with an external tool and set it to the button.
I was thinking of taking same color as parent or something like that but I don't know if that exists.

[main.dart](https://gist.github.com/AzerSD/df9b7ede44be2ae4ea110b0052576c5b)

[WelcomeScreen.dart](https://gist.github.com/AzerSD/61b5d4bcbde85017f0ff340c63b3fc69)

Comment: just set the color of the login container to `Colors.transparent`

Comment: I have a shadow behind the containers, so if I set the color to transparent I'll see the shadow instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaffold background color is `Grey[50]`. You can set background color on scaffold like

```dart
Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

Or for app

```dart
  return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
```

More about [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html).